# Open preferences menu from andengine sprite touch

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, andengine, preferenceactivity

I am creating a full-screen andengine GLES2 based app.

In the app there are some settings that the user can select, and I've used the PreferencesActivity available in android.

All of this works if the device has a physical menu button.  Since this button will be disappearing over time, I have added a ButtonSprite to my screen that I would like to open the preferences activity as if the menu button was pressed.  I am not using an action bar as this is a full screen app and do not want to forfeit any more screen real estate.

I have everything wired up so that I know when the button is touched, but am at a loss to determine what I should call to instantiate the preferences activity.

I am sure that this is a simple matter, however, the documentation and examples have not provided any clues, at least to me.

So, given that I know where to place the call to get the preferences activity displayed, what do I call to actually get this to happen?

Thanks in advance,

B.

Answer (score 2):

To open a new activity, you need to fire an Intent. From your main activity, it could look like:

```
Intent i = new Intent();
i.setClassname(this, "your.package.name.PreferencesActivity");
this.startActivity(i);
```

However, you'll be in the context of wherever your button click handler is, so you'll need to reference your current activity instead of `this`.